# Query many-to-many relationship with UserId error - MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So i've created a many-to-many relationship between the UserProfile table created by the simplemembership and an Enrollment table created by me.

UserProfile -> User_Enrollment <- Enrollment

I'm trying to query the enrollments of the user logged in and i have this code:

```
public ActionResult ListarUCs()
        {
    var id = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
    var ucs = db.Enrollments.Where(x => x.Users.Any(r => id.Equals(r.UserId)));

            return View(ucs.ToList());
        }
```

Being Users the name of the List of UserProfiles in Enrollments model.
But it gives an error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type System.object. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Already tried this way:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

and then the query, but it doesn't recognize the User.Identity.GetUserId();

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: If you are using SimpleMembership, I would recommend using WebSecurity.CurrentUserId to get the userId, or WebSecurity.CurrentUserName to get the Username of the current logged in user

Answer (score 0):

Try getting current user from db and then querying directly the relationship, something more or less like this...

```
public ActionResult ListarUCs() {
    aspnet_Users userInSession = db.aspnet_Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName.ToLower() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower());
    IEnumerable<Enrollments> ucs = userInSession.User_Enrollment.SelectMany(e => e.Enrollment);

    return View(ucs);
}
```